# Modify a subset of a pandas column using data from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to modify specific values in a column, where the modification uses values from another column. For example say I have a df:

```
A    B    C
1    3    8
1    6    8
2    2    9
2    6    1
3    4    5
3    6    7
```

Where I want `df['B'] = df['B'] + df['C']` only for the subset `df.loc[df['A'] == 2]`

Producing:

```
A    B    C
1    3    8
1    6    8
2    11   9
2    7    1
3    4    5
3    6    7
```

I have tried

`df.loc[(df['A']==2), 'B'].apply(lambda x: x + df['C'])`

but get:

**InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close, apply is not necessary:

```
m = df['A'] == 2
#short way
df.loc[m, 'B'] += df.loc[m, 'C']
#long way
df.loc[m, 'B'] = df.loc[m, 'B'] + df.loc[m, 'C']
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 2, 'B'] += df['C']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `numpy`, I find it very simple for tasks like yours:

```
import numpy as np
df['B'] =  np.where(df['A'] == 2, df['B']+df['C'],df['B'])
```

prints:

```
   A   B  C
0  1   3  8
1  1   6  8
2  2  11  9
3  2   7  1
4  3   4  5
5  3   6  7
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've upvoted but accepted the pandas method purely because that was what I was using :)

Comment: Of course, just wanted to point out an alternative.